# Undefined var in chrome console after elixir webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, vue.js

I have a js file scripts.js with vue js code:

```
var app2  = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    data:{
        message: 'Some msg'
    }
})
```

Then I build js file with gulp elixir webpack

```
elixir((mix) => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js')
});
```

Then i load public/js/app.js file in html and everyting works well.
But if i try to log this var, i get an undefined error.

```
console.log(app2); //undefined
```

If i will load scripts.js to html without webpack, it will be ok.

Then how can I log this variable after webpack build?
Thanks

Comment: probably after the build the code is minified or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this variable is minified and sandboxed and is not available in global scope. If you want to have access to this variable after minification you have to bind it somehow to the global scope.

For example you could do:

```
var app2  = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    data:{
        message: 'Some msg'
    }
});
window["app2"] = app2;
//window.app2 = app2;  <- it should also work
```

This way `app2` will be always available in the global context of the browser.